# How can I connect with a database deployed at Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, influxdb, amazon-eks, influxdb-python

So, I have my `Influx` database deployed at my `AWS Kubernetes Cluster(EKS)`. 
What I want is to be able to connect with the database with my `python` project and be able to query the database. 
I can see that I can use the Influx API ,like these [examples](https://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html) , but I cannot configure the database since it is not deployed locally.
How am I supposed to configure the database now that it is deployed in the EKS? 
I did a little research but nothing helped so far.
I am new to Kubernetes and Influx so maybe this is a simple issue , in any case any advice or tip would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your Influx Service type to `LoadBalancer` type would give you an external IP for your Influx instance, then you can connect to Influx with that IP from your Python code.
You can take a look [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/).

Comment: Thank you , I changed it and now it work as it is supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

you can try [port-forwarding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/#forward-a-local-port-to-a-port-on-the-pod) to access your database locally .
try this

```
 kubectl port-forward pod-name -n namespace localport:podport
```

> pod-name -- your influxdb pod name
>
> localport -- the port that you want to use locally(try 8086).
>
> podport -- the port which is exposed by pod (i believe this is 8086).

now try to access db locally by localhost:8086

this is temporary solution. You need to create a service or route to use db outside the cluster.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , I actually did hxquangnhat's answer and it worked.